# ERROR: (subscript) logical subscript too long

Tags: r

I am trying to remove a row of a dataframe in R however because the dataframe is so large when I use:

```
rawCounts <- rawCounts[rawCounts != geneID, ]
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR in rawCounts[rawCounts != geneID, ]: (subscript) logical subscript too long
```

Is there another way of removing a specific row in a large dataframe that is not so memory intensive?

Thanks in advance.

I have quite a bit of memory, memory.limit() returns:

```
> memory.limit()
[1] 16318
```

Answer (score 2):

I am answering my own question here.

I realised I should have been using

```
rawCounts <- rawCounts[rownames(rawCounts) != geneID, ]
```

Problem solved.